# JSON parsing in MySQL while selecting

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I have a little problem with MySQL. Here is my situation:

I have a table named `items` with a column named `fields` that contains JSON data. This is how the value looks:

```
example row1: [{"id":"1","value":"1"},{"id":"2","value":"2"},{"id":"3","value":"1"}]
example row2: [{"id":"1","value":"1"},{"id":"2","value":"7"},{"id":"3","value":"1"}]
```

My query should be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE  `fields` has {"id":"2","value":"2"}
```

And this:

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `items` WHERE `fields` has {"id":"2","value":"2"}
```

But I don't know how to do this. The biggest problem is that this has to be fast because my row count is big. It would be really great if you could help me out here or give me a link with information, I tried to search but all I found common_schema methods but people say those are slow. Thanks in advance!

Comment: very very bad table structure.

Comment: @echo_Me I know, but i did not make it. And now I am the one who has to deal with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a *relatively* close solution:

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `items` WHERE `fields` like '%"id":"2","value":"2"%'
```

(It is white space sensitive...)

Comment: Well, I guess it's the only choice. Thanks!